# Adding data to Pandas Dataframe in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to populate a pandas dataframe from multiple dictionaries. Each of the dictionaries are in the form below:

`{'Miami': {'DrPepper': '5', 'Pepsi': '8'}}`

`{'Atlanta:{'DrPepper':'10','Pepsi':'25'}}`

Ultimately what I want is a dataframe that looks like this (After this I plan to use pandas to do some data transformations then output the dataframe to a tab delimited file):

```
      DrPepper  Pepsi
Miami    5       8
Atlanta  10      25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using an additional library, you can use [`toolz.merge`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.merge) to combine all of the dictionaries, followed by [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
import toolz

d1 = {'Miami': {'DrPepper': '5', 'Pepsi': '8'}}
d2 = {'Atlanta': {'DrPepper': '10', 'Pepsi': '25'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(toolz.merge(d1, d2), orient='index')
```

This method assumes that you don't have repeat index values (i.e city names).  If you do, the repeats will be overwritten with the last one in the list of dictionaries taking precedence.

The resulting output:

```
        DrPepper Pepsi
Atlanta       10    25
Miami          5     8
```

Comment: yet again, you've taught me something tremendously useful.

Comment: @piRSquared: Thanks, I've found that the [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library contains tons of useful small functions.  Seems like a package you'd enjoy.  Also note that there's [`cytoolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz), which is a cython implementation of `toolz` for enhanced performance

Comment: I have never heard of the toolz library, thanks for this recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) `DataFrames` created from `dict` by [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
d1 = {'Miami': {'DrPepper': '5', 'Pepsi': '8'}}
d2 = {'Atlanta':{'DrPepper':'10','Pepsi':'25'}}

print (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index'))
      Pepsi DrPepper
Miami     8        5

print (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index'),
                  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2, orient='index')]))
        Pepsi DrPepper
Miami       8        5
Atlanta    25       10
```

Another solution with `transpose` by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame(d1))
         Miami
DrPepper     5
Pepsi        8

print (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d1).T, pd.DataFrame(d2).T]))
        DrPepper Pepsi
Miami          5     8
Atlanta       10    25
```

Is possible use `list comprehension` also:

```
L = [d1,d2]
print (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d).T for d in L]))
        DrPepper Pepsi
Miami          5     8
Atlanta       10    25
```